# Wiris math editor

Tags: php, tinymce

I need help. I installed the Wiris math editor, but it does not work. Creating math works well, but the display does not work.

I know why, but I do not know how I repair it: I use free hosting which paste advertisement into the website's URL.

I want the URL to look like:

```
http://u12.hys.cz/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/showim‌​age.php?formula=3b1e36f0f64404ca46029248411a14da&cw=20&ch=13&cb=12&text=55
```

while my provider changes it to:

```
http://u12.hys.cz/%3Cdiv%20style=%22%20background-color:#; font-size: px;"><div class="trop"><strong>Magnetická </strong>kostka <a href="http://unimagnet.cz/20-k-d5-neocube-216kusu.html" title="NeoCube">NeoCube</a> na prodej</div></div>/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=3b1e36f0f64404ca46029248411a14da&cw=20&ch=13&cb=12&text=55
```

Note that the provider added the following part

```
%3Cdiv%20style=%22%20background-color:#; font-size: px;"><div class="trop"><strong>Magnetická </strong>kostka<a href="http://unimagnet.cz/20-k-d5-neocube-216kusu.html" title="NeoCube">NeoCube</a> na prodej</div></div>
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: On localhost everything works correctly, but my hosting provider paste advertisement into every page and this advertisement is in URL adress, but I do not why.

Comment: What is the URL you want and what does the provider add? Could you clarify that in the question (by editing)? That would make it clearer.

Comment: I need: `htttp://u12.hys.cz/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=3b1e36f0f64404ca46029248411a14da&cw=20&ch=13&cb=12&text=55`

Comment: Provider add: `%3Cdiv%20style=%22%20background-color:#; font-size: px;"><div class="trop"><strong>Magnetická </strong>kostka <a href="http://unimagnet.cz/20-k-d5-neocube-216kusu.html" title="NeoCube">NeoCube</a> na prodej</div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is **not** related to WIRIS plugin but to an advertisment your server provider is including in the image URL generated by our plugin. We are not sure when does your server provider modify the image link but we output the image link in //integration/createimage.php where you could probably remove the advertisment.

Comment: Hi, can you please answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66659122/ckeditor-wiris-mathtype-not-parsing-math-ml-in-edit-mode